# Taking input strings and numbers into 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

Having difficulty taking in data (string and number) for participants.  The idea is to create a program which will take in data into arrays (name and time separately) and eventually analyse the data by name and time

Here's my code attempt...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RaceTimes
{

public static void main (String[] args)

{
    int num;

    Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Athletic Statistical Analysis Application");
    System.out.println("******************************************************************* \n");


    System.out.println("Please input number of participants ");

    num=input.nextInt();

    // If the user enters an invalid number... display error message... ask again for valid input number
    while(num<2|| num >10)
    {
        System.out.println("Error invalid input! Try again! \nPlease input a valid number of participants...");

         num=input.nextInt();
    }


    double resultArray [] = new double [num]; // create result array with new operator
    String nameArray [] = new String [num];// create name array with new operator
    // Using the num int will ensure that the array holds the number of elements inputed by user

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nameArray.length ; i++)
    System.out.println ("Please enter a race participant Name for runner " + (i+1) );

    //nameArray [1] = input.nextString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there!

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < nameArray.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println ("Please enter a race participant Name for runner " + (i+1) );
    nameArray[i] = input.next();
    System.out.println ("Please enter a race result for runner " + (i+1) );
    resultArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
```

That should do it.

You might want to add something here to cope with values that are out of range, or things that can't be interpreted as floating point numbers. You'd need a `try`/`catch` block to catch `InputMismatchException` in order to deal appropriately with someone entering something that can't be interpreted as a number. (The `.nextDouble()` method will throw this exception if it can't parse the input.)

Comment: Thanks! Works great for the race result but for the string part I'm still getting an error.   error: cannot find symbol
      nameArray[i] = input.nextString();  symbol:   method nextString()
  location: variable input of type Scanner
1 error

Comment: Tried to compile it in Eclipse too...  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method nextString() is undefined for the type Scanner

Comment: Is the Scanner not willing to take the Strings input?

Comment: @CassyHiggins sorry, that was a typo! Corrected now. It's just `.next()` to read in a `String`.